# font awesome icons inside asp textbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to include an `<i></i>` inside the asp text box in gridview but it's not working.I have tried this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="modify" runat="server" Text='<i class='icon-edit'></i>'/></asp:TextBox>
```

and i also tried

```
<asp:TextBox ID="modify" runat="server"><i class="icon-edit"></i></asp:TextBox>
```

Any Idea?

I know that, I have tried and all, but I cant see icon.
I want to include font awesome icon inside the `gridview` textbox.

I have used this class only.

```
.icon-edit{
content: "\f057";
left: auto;
right: 16px;
padding: 0 3px;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 1px;
line-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting source code. It would be helpful if you could provide the generated HTML.
Pls shre the HTML code as received by the browser. You can either use
- view source option in browser,
- inspect element option. Are you able to get the icon display outside the gridbox?

Comment: can you try &lt; class='icon-edit' &gt; in the text attribute? but why do you want to have a tag inside of a text??

Answer (score 0):

The `<asp:TextBox />` tag creates an `<input type="text" />` html element.  `input` elements can't contain additional markup.  So what you want to do is put your `<i>` after the textbox, and then use css to move it over so that it appears to be positioned on top of the textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="modify" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><i class="icon-edit"></i>
```

Then css:

```
.icon-edit {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

This is just an example, you'll need to play around with the css to get things looking the way you want.